# Copying code from PDF changes apostrophes and quotations, which breaks the code

Tags: phpstorm

Trying to copy PHP code out of the PDF textbook in Adobe Acrobat Reader, however whenever I copy some code it always changes the `'` apostrophes into those weird italicized apostrophes, which then completely breaks the code.

How do I get it to copy and paste from the PDF into PhpStorm without changing the apostrophes? It also does the same thing to quotations.

Comment: **1)** Try with `Edit | Paste Simple` instead of just `Paste` **2)** If nothing -- try via intermediate plain text editor first (e.g. Notepad++ on Windows) -- Paste there first then select it again and only then copy-paste into PhpStorm. **P.S.** I've removed language-specific tags (php, css, html) as they seem to be irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Control + Shift + V into a text editor and then copy+paste to PHPStorm?

Comment: Please state full action name and not just shortcut alone -- on another OS / another keymap that shortcut may do completely different thing.